# How to write case statements per family in R

Tags: r

How do I properly write a case statement according to the `family` class. I currently match by string, but what is the proper way to do this.

```
gigl <- function(family = poisson()){

  if (family == "binomial"){
  print(1)}

  else if(family == "guassian"){
  print(2)}

  else {
  print(3)}
}
```

The output should be

```
> gigl(family = poisson())
3

> gigl(family = binomial())
1

> gigl(family =  gaussian())
2
```

Comment: `gigl <- function(family = poisson()) match(family$family, c('binomial', 'gaussian', 'poisson'))` or `gigl <- function(family = poisson()) match(family$family, c('binomial', 'gaussian'), nomatch = 3)` I can't tell what you want for anything not binomial/gaussian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a switch statement:

```
gigl <- function(family = poisson()){
  x <- switch(family$family,
              binomial = 1,
              gaussian = 2,
              3)
}
```

You might prefer `dplyr::case_when` :

```
gigl2 <- function(family = poisson()){
  dplyr::case_when(family$family == 'binomial' ~ 1,
                   family$family == 'gaussian' ~ 2,
                   TRUE ~ 3)
}
```

Results:

```
gigl(family = poisson())
# [1] 3

gigl(family = binomial())
# [1] 1

gigl(family =  gaussian())
# [1] 2

gigl2(family = poisson())
# [1] 3

gigl2(family = binomial())
# [1] 1

gigl2(family =  gaussian())
# [1] 2
```